# How to read this method name?

Tags: java, class

I'm profiling my Java 8 application and came across the following method name in the section "hottest methods":

```
pack.age.MyClassName.lambda$convert$7d345dcf$1(List, Map, MyClass, MyClass)
```

So what does `MyClassName.lambda$convert$7d345dcf$1` mean?

Comment: It's a method generated by the compiler.  Probably for a lambda expression.

Comment: It means, that an anonymous method has been created. It does not have a name and exists only while executing it.

Comment: it´s a generated method-name of the compiler to access and log private classes/methods and a way to print them for you. You can have a look [here](http://www.retrologic.com/innerclasses.doc7.html) to read it in detail.